# How to print more than one div at the same time in same pdf?

Tags: jquery

I am using following script to print a certain div as a pdf file.

```
(function ($) {
$('.print-me').on('click', function () {
var $areaToPrint = $($(this).data('print-me'));
var $hiddenAreas = $('.hide-print');
if ($areaToPrint.length) {
$hiddenAreas.hide();
$areaToPrint.show();
window.print();
$hiddenAreas.show();
}
});
})(jQuery);
```

But I am not able to print more than one div with different ids on the same pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you put the ID of the element to print into `$(this).data('print-me')`. That makes it hard to select more than a single element.

To achieve what you want, you should assign a class to all `div`s that you want to print instead (i.e. `.printable`). That would allow you to

```
var $areaToPrint = $('.printable');
```

and get several elements. The rest of the code would then be the same.

**EDIT** I make your code work here: https://jsfiddle.net/051nbtcL/2/

HTML

```
<div class="print-me">First Paragraph</div>
<div class="print-me">Second Paragraph</div>
<div class="hide-print">Always Hidden</div>

<button id="print" class="hide-print">Print</button>
```

Important details:

```
$('.print-me').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hide-print');
});
```

will toggle the class `hide-print` when you click a printable element. I'm using CSS styling to make it easy to see which elements have this style.

In the `button`'s click handler, I first locate all elements which have the `print-me` class and then remove those which also have `hide-print` to find out if there is anything to print at all.

```
$('#print').on('click', function () {
    var $areaToPrint = $('.print-me').filter(function(index){
        return !$(this).hasClass('hide-print');
    });
    var $hiddenAreas = $('.hide-print');
```

In the `if()`, I only have to hide the hidden elements (the other are visible and stay visible), print and restore:

```
    if ($areaToPrint.length) {
        $hiddenAreas.hide();

        window.print();
        $hiddenAreas.show();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the code. Can you look at it again and change your answer?

Comment: Please don't change questions like that. My answer now doesn't make sense anymore. Keep in mind that questions and answers are not for you alone; other people will eventually see them as well. Revert the change and ask a new question.

Comment: actually the above code was mistake and it doesnot even work. demo https://jsfiddle.net/051nbtcL/

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you one way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I just want to deal with ´.print-med´  but not with ´.hide-print´ because I have classes inside classes so assigning ´.hide-print´ and ´.print-me´ is just too much.

Comment: My approach allows you to distinguish between elements that are always printed (give them `print-me` and don't allow to toggle `hide-print` for then), elements which can be toggled and elements which are never printed. With small changes to the code and/or using more classes, you should be able to achieve what you need.